# How to exclude words from match in regex?

Tags: regex

I am trying to exclude certain URLs from a match, containing `/com/de/cms/` e.g.:

match this:

> www.example.com/catname/all-from-category/?pageNumber=1

but not this:

> example.com/com/de/cms/catname/all-from-category/?pageNumber=3

Regex:

```
^[^com\/de\/cms\/]+\/all-from-category\/\?pageNumber=\d(&hitsPerPage=\d)?
```

https://regex101.com/r/Mqpspq/1

How can I exclude URLs with `com/de/cms/` while matching the other URL?

Comment: Your regex is probably missing `"catname"` ?

Comment: I thought  that the "+" means all but the string defined before. Which would include "catname". Is this wrong?

Comment: `+` means one or more occurrence of what's before.

Comment: yes, but the ^ will exclude the words defined in braket, right? That would therefore allow /catname/ if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Yes, but the brackets are a set. So I believe it would be looking for no `c`, `o`, `m`, `/`, `d`, `e`, or `s` rather then those whole strings.

Comment: You need the *negative lookahead* `(?!.*\/com\/de/cms\/)` after the beginning-of-line anchor, but there are other problems with your regex. For one, since `(&hitsPerPage=\d)?` is at the end of the regex and is optional it has no effect.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thank you! That seems to work: "^(?!.*\/com\/de/cms\/).*\/all-from-category\/\?pageNumber=\d(&hitsPerPage=\d)?$"

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of mistakes in your regex.

1. The first `^` matches the **start** of the starting, or the start of a line if multiline mode is enabled.
2. The `[^com\/de\/cms]` part means to match any **character** except `c`, or `o`, or `m` or `/`, or, etc. But your intent was to match any **substring** except `com/de/cms` as a whole. What you want can be done using *negative lookbehind*, like this: `(?<!com\/de\/cms\/)`
3. You're missing the `catname` part.

A working regex would be:

`(?<!com\/de\/cms)\/catname\/all-from-category\/\?pageNumber=\d`

The previous regex is simply says the following:

Please, match `/catname/all-from-category/?pageNumber=SOME_DIGIT` that is **not** preceded by `com/de/cms`.

[Regexr](https://regexr.com/55i1v).

Comment: My intention was also to match any string before the "/all-from-category" except the defined words. This would include "catname" as this is is just a placeholder for any category name there would be. If I substitute the catname in your regex with .* it will again match also the unintended line.

Comment: For me, it worked if I replaced `catname` with `[^/]+`.

Comment: Yousef, the question says that URL's containing `com/de/cms` are to be excluded, without qualification of where they appear in the string. Accordingly, you need a *negative lookahead* rather than a negative lookbehind. See my comment on the question.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks for your comments, they're correct. However, It seems that OP knows where `com/de/cms` will be in the url. From my understanding, `com/de/cms` will always be followed by a category name, then `/all-from-category/....etc`.

For the catname part, it will work just perfectly if he applied duckboycool's suggestion to use `[^\/]+` as the category name will never contains a `/`.